# NullPointerException when setting viewPager.setCurrentItem

Tags: java, android

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                         at com.example.iswipe.MainActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(MainActivity.java:68)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

public static String POSITION = "POSITION";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpPager);

    // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(POSITION, tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(POSITION)); <----------- LINE 68
}
```

Hi, I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) to learning **(Getting or Selected the Current Page)**. Stating that I can save and restore the last known tab position by implementing methods on *onSaveInstanceState()* and *onRestoreInstanceState()* to persist this data during screen rotation.

But I'm getting NPE on line 68. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving your `ViewPager` instance in a local variable in `onCreate`. You should save it in the field instead.

You can either

- add `viewPager = vpPager;` to onCreate

Or

- replace `ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);` with `viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);` and replace every use of `vpPager` with `viewPager`.

*I recommend that you try to really understand what the problem here is. It will help you to improve your programming skills.*

Comment: Thks I found the problem! Was in the mist of changing the variables names but I guess i missed that one out.

Comment: However, does onSaveInstanceState and onRestore.... runs when I press the Hardware Back button? Because it doesnt returns the tab position if I press Back button. It does revert the tab position if I press the Home button.

Comment: This is a different question. Please look at the documentation or open a new question. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html